# Inserting Handlebars to the DOM in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am generating a list of checkboxes & radio buttons based on data coming from a server. The page is a Handlebars template using Ember. To generate my list on the page, I am using the following line of code:

```
document.getElementById('radioList').innerHTML = newHtml;
```

This works fine if `newHtml` is set to something like:

```
<li><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio /><label for="radio1">List item one</label></li>
```

However, I'd like events to be triggered based on these radio buttons (or checkboxes) being selected or unselected - and after some googling, it would seem using Handlebars helpers is the way to go. But when I try to insert the radio button using handlebars, with the `newHtml` set as such:

```
<li>{{input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio }}<label for="radio1">List item one</label></li>
```

The text just appears rather than a radio button itself. Looking further into this seems to suggest that the Handlebars template I'm inserting into needs recompiled? I may be wrong, but I've spent quite a bit of time searching for answers to this problem and can't seem to find them. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried jquery change event?

Comment: Yes you need to compile this code first and going with inner HTML direct change is not the way to go.

Comment: I had a look at implementing onclick, but it would seem Ember doesn't like that too much and getting around it is quite a bit of hassle (I'm not very experienced yet!), would jquery change run into the same trouble?

Comment: Can you please paste how you done on change event, with jquery.

Comment: `<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio onclick=function(this) />`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to do this with jQuery.

**Triggering using button for example**

```
<h2>Click and select radio button</h2>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Generate"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="hid" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var generatedradios=$("#hid").val();

    var str='<input type="radio" class="generated" data-generated="'+generatedradios+'" id="radio1" name="radio" />';
    $("#hid").val(Number(generatedradios)+1);
    $("body").append(str);
});

$(document).on("change",".generated",function(){
   alert($(this).attr("data-generated")); 
});
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/Isakkiraj/wLg1p8as/